# Rewrite (append) SAS token to url in azure cdn

Tags: azure, url-rewriting, azure-cdn

I have been trying to get azure cdn using verizon p1 to append sas token to any url that acesses my blob which is hosting a static website.

The original URL was like
https://myproject.blob.core.windows.net/mzz-stage/index.html

The CDN url would be
https://mzz-stage.azureedge.net/

I plan to provide the url to the end user as
https://mzz-stage.azureedge.net/mzz-stage/index.html

My URL Rewrite rule looks like this

[image]

I am getting an error as such :

[image]

I feel that this has to do with an incorrect rewrite rule, the rule is supposed to append the url with a sas token to any url that contains mzz-stage in the uri.

PS: The containers and blobs are set to private.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have provided the rules accordingly,

```
Source: /<Origin>/<ContainerPath>/(.*)

Destination: /<Origin>/<ContainerPath>/$1<SAS>&<Source>
```

Also note that it can take up to 4 hrs for the new rule to get propagated.

Comment: Unfortunately we decided to scrap the cdn, so I was never able to test this but Thank you!